# How to save the history of the results in Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want my app to save all of the results and later to display it in a "History" activity , where the user can view the recent history of the results. The results are some numbers.

I can create a new database and add every result there , but i think this might increase the size of my app significantly. Is this a good approach?

Please  could you give me some suggestions? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can save it on the server or in SharedPreferences.

Comment: Yes i thought of using SharedPreferences , but lthe user may decide to delete the history. Can this be done with SharedPreferences.

Comment: Sure, you just remove the data from shared preferences... You should store them in some structured way any way, and limit them (like 500 at most, or something), so the size will not grow over some limit.

Comment: Yeah, you can delete sharedPrefs. Both clear the whole thing and delete 1 by 1 entry.

Comment: Awesome , thanks fellas